# How keycloak user gets access to different clients?

Tags: keycloak

In our company we have different applications like Jira, Confluence, GitLab and also applications developed by our developers. For authentication in listed applications we use SSO based on Keycloak.

The listed applications can have some permissions. Where do they store their permissions? Do they sync users from Keycloak to their own databases? If no (no id for Keycloak users) how do they attach permissions with users?

Comment: Users who exist in a given realm can have access to any/all applications in that realm

Comment: The listed applications can use keycloak level permissions, which are managed in the keycloak admin panel in a given realm, but consuming applications can also choose to store permissions for users however they choose for their own personal applications. If using keycloak permissions, clients (applications) must have the ability to access the same permissions in keycloak that the users have

Comment: You will need to create roles in keyloak assign them to the user and depending on how the applications (jira ect) reads them you will have to map those keycloak roles to permission that the applications will understand